# How to add multiple images upon glass texture on a mesh?

Tags: texturing, uv, image, shader-nodes, glass

I know what you are thinking: "This question has been asked before!" Well, this is a bit different. I am designing a glass plate, and I want to have two little checkmarks on the bottom, on either corner. Now, **how can I layer the two images upon the glass plate?** I have gotten fairly close, where each checkmark is in the right spot, the glass texture is correct, yadda yadda yadda, but I don't know exactly how to *mix* them with the glass texture, so they are like stickers. Should I be using a MixRGB node or a MixShader node...?

Comment: Use a mix shader combining your checkmarks with the glass material, using a black and white (Rgb to Bw + ColorRamp) version of the checkmarks as a mask (mix factor).

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @Christopher Bennet (see comments) for this answer:

> Use a mix shader combining your checkmarks with the glass material, using a black and white (Rgb to Bw + ColorRamp) version of the checkmarks as a mask (mix factor).

Thanks Chris! It worked!